# A sorted and filtered treemodel in Python Gtk+3..?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to get a treemodel (a liststore in fact) that can be filtered and also sorted. I have the following piece of code

```
self.modelfilter = self.liststore.filter_new()
self.modelfilter.set_visible_func(\
            self._visible_filter_function)
self.treeview.set_model(self.modelfilter)
```

where `self.liststore` and `self.treeview` are standard `Gtk.ListStore` and `Gtk.TreeView` objects that I get from a glade file, and `self._visible_filter_function` is a filtering function.

The problem is that `self.modelfilter` does not seem to be sortable. When I click on the column headers (of the columns in `self.treeview`) to sort them, I get

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_sortable_get_sort_column_id: assertion `GTK_IS_TREE_SORTABLE (sortable)' failed
```

saying that the treemodel is not sortable.

This problem seems to be surmountable in PyGtk as suggested [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2005-February/msg00180.html). The idea is to stack a ListStore, a TreeModelFilter and a TreeSortFilter one inside the other and feed the last one as the model for the treeview.

However this trick does not seem to be working in Python Gtk+3. When I try

```
self.modelfilter = self.liststore.filter_new()
self.modelfilter.set_visible_func(\
            self._visible_filter_function)
self.sorted_and_filtered_model = \
            Gtk.TreeModelSort(self.modelfilter)
self.treeview.set_model(self.sorted_and_filtered_model)
```

it complains

```
Gtk.TreeModelSort(self.modelfilter)
TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

Now I tried to get a instance of `Gtk.TreeModelSort` with no arguments. But this instance does not have any `set_model` method.

I am lost here.

Is there another way to set the model for `Gtk.TreeModelSort`? Or is there a totally different way to get a filtered and sortable treemodel object that can be displayed in a treeview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> mymodel = Gtk.ListStore()
>>> Gtk.TreeModelSort(model=mymodel)
<TreeModelSort object at 0x1d4d190 (GtkTreeModelSort at 0x1f0d3f0)>
```

In my opinion PyGObject is not ready yet. It has no browsable documentation, some things are not instrospected yet and in particular this:

- Sometimes a widget work with Gtk.MyWidget(attr=foo), like this one.
- Sometimes with Gtk.MyWidget.new_with_label('Foo'), like buttons. Yes, Gtk.MyWidget(label='Foo') doesn't work.

Kind regards

Comment: Superb..! This works. As you say, it is very hard to find out this is the way to go as there is very little documentation. Thanks.