# Python GTK +3: Sorting a treeview by clicking on column

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to be able to sort a treeview by column by clicking on a column. I'm simply using the popular example taken from the docs as reference (https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treeview.html):

```
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.filter)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"]):
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)
            column.set_sort_column_id(i)
```

except I get the error:

(test.py:26081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 12:35:03.856: gtk_tree_sortable_get_sort_column_id: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_SORTABLE (sortable)' failed

(test.py:26081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 12:35:03.856: gtk_tree_sortable_has_default_sort_func: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_SORTABLE (sortable)' failed

(test.py:26081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 12:35:03.856: gtk_tree_sortable_set_sort_column_id: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_SORTABLE (sortable)' failed

Comment: Not sure if is a duplicate, but this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368059/a-sorted-and-filtered-treemodel-in-python-gtk3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368059/a-sorted-and-filtered-treemodel-in-python-gtk3), I figured a way.

Edit the following line:

```
self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.filter)
```

in

```
self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(Gtk.TreeModelSort(self.filter))
```

and should work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by  Valentino will only allow the user to sort the tree by default sort method. If you need to sort with a custom function you can do so. by doing this.

Create a Gtk.TreeModelSort object with filter and assign a sort fucntion.

```
    sorted_model = Gtk.TreeModelSort(model=self.filter)
    sorted_model.set_sort_func(0, self.sort_tree, None)
```

Then Set the treeview with this sort model.

```
    self.tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(model=sorted_model)
```

This worked for me.